# Prevent showing Login screen after user login

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

Web Apllication shows login screen after logged in when i click back button in browser.

I am using spring framework. Is there any Solution for this?

Comment: The back button is for.. Well, getting to the page before the current one, so I think it's correct... Would you like your users to press "back" and confuse them by showing something they don't expect? :)

Comment: Think about face book, what happens if you click back button after you logged in. it simply shows home page.

Comment: Exactly my point :) I press "back" on facebook and the browser doesn't do what I wanted.. Well I guess it's a matter of taste anyway ^^

Comment: Hey Jori , Do you want to log in to the system in second time ? :):)

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions. If he has logged in, save his username, or id to a session variable. At your login page, make sure to check that session. If it exists, redirect him to another page. Else, login.

Comment: I have done this, but this is not work with clicking back button in the browser, I think some kind of caching happen

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using self-implemented authentication tools unless there is a strong reason not to use existing libraries (very rare case, based on my experience).You might want to check out spring-security, a project which could deliver pretty much everything you might need in terms of securing your web application. You definitely can achieve this behavior using this library. Although, it didn't work properly in Mozilla Firefox, if I recall. I guess Mozilla just reads the webapp from cache and doesn't even communicate to the server in such cases. But I might be wrong here.